# solve sytem of binary equations

Tags: matrix, binary, gaussian

If I have a bunch of semi-random binary equations (not necessarily linear equations), how would I go about solving them?  For 2-3 variables, a k-map is usually sufficient, but what about 100 variables and 100 equations?

The equations themselves have xor, and, & not operations.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "solve" in this context. Do you want to find a single set of values for the variables that satisfy all equations (the usual notion of solving a system of equations), or are you trying to reduce the set of equations to a single equation that specifies all possible solutions? A k-map is usually for simplifying a single equation in multiple variables - not sure how you would use it with multiple equations...

Comment: I would like to find a single set of values for the variables that satisfy all of the equations.

Comment: @twalberg Also, I believe these are linear equations.  A simple example: "A xor (B xor (C and !D)) = 1"

Comment: Not sure what tools you have for this, but I know Matlab and Octave both have modules/functions/packages to deal with matrices in GF(2) (which is what Boolean variables are, for the most part). I'm a little rusty on what the term "linear" means with respect to GF(2)...

Comment: I don't think that looks like a linear equation, though - a linear equation would look like (using c<n> for coefficients, v<n> for variables, x for XOR and + for AND) "c<n> x v<n> + ... + c1 x v1 + c0 = k" where all the c<n> and k are either 0 or 1... If you have terms that XOR multiple variables together, that's most likely non-linear...